# Как сделать такую кнопку CSS

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна кнопка на которой написано "man". Как сделать такую на css? Если можно с адаптивом, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой вариант.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #978585;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  --rotate-shadow: 70deg;
}

.button::before,
.button::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #303030;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform:
    skewX(var(--rotate-shadow))
    translateX(-.5px);
}

.button::after {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: 
    skewY(calc(90deg - var(--rotate-shadow)))
    translateY(-.5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">MAN</div>
```